# Batch loop to run program with a series of combinations

Tags: batch-file

Given the following:

```
set program_name= "path/to/program"
set X= Platinum, Gold, Silver, Bronze
set Y= A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I
set Z= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
set n_runs= 4
```

I would like to run a series of nested loops that run 4 individual processes at the same time like the following:

```
FOR %%x in (%X%) DO ( 
    FOR %%y in (%Y%) DO (
        FOR %%z in (%Z%) DO (
            call :do_while_loop_start
            Start "program" "%program_name%" -b -list1 %%x -list2 %%y -list3 %%z filename_~list1~_~list2~_~list3~_.txt
            timeout 30
        )
    )
)

Pause
 
:do_while_loop_start
    set /a count=0
    for /f %%x in ('tasklist ^| find /c "that_task"') do set count=%%x
    if %count% geq %n_runs% (
        PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL
        goto do_while_loop_start
)
```

These nested for loops run well if I need to run the processes having the files with all the elements in the list "Z".
The problem that I now have is for every element in list "X" and "Y" I have few elements of list "Z" to run. Examples of the processes I have to run are:

```
...
filename_~Platinum~_~A~_~5~_.txt
filename_~Platinum~_~A~_~8~_.txt
filename_~Platinum~_~A~_~9~_.txt
filename_~Platinum~_~B~_~1~_.txt
filename_~Platinum~_~B~_~2~_.txt
filename_~Platinum~_~B~_~10~_.txt
filename_~Platinum~_~C~_~4~_.txt
filename_~Platinum~_~C~_~8~_.txt
filename_~Platinum~_~C~_~9~_.txt
filename_~Platinum~_~C~_~10~_.txt
...
```

I will still need to run all elements in lists "X" and "Y" but not all elements in list "Z", and the items in Z vary each time for every "X" "Y" combination (i.e. could be 3 elements, could be 6, could be 2, could be non sequential, etc...)
Is there a way I could run all these processes in an automated way? If it's not possible, I am happy to state explicitly every combination but I will need to run 4 processes at the time using the `:do_while_loop_start routine` How can I achieve this?

Hope it makes sense
Thank you!

Comment: How do you know which elements in Z get used with which combinations of X and Y?

Comment: You could do something similar to key value pairs.  I know we have an example of it here on StackOverFlow or Dostips.com. So you could have a variable set like: `set "values=A=5,8,9;B=1,2,10"`.  I will see if I can find that question and answer for you. I know we have covered logic like this.

Comment: @SomethingDark - because I have a series of combinations, a total of 148 .txt files. I have them written all down and they generally follow the example above.

Comment: Okay, the problem is definitely not a programming problem, but a requirements problem. There is no rule which defines which elements of Z can be used with which elements combinations of X and Y. Squashman has asked already for that rule. A list of .txt file names on a paper is of no help for batch file code as the Windows command processor cannot scan the paper, run an OCR and interpret the resulting text. It is definitely necessary to define either one or more rules to select the Z elements suitable for current combination of X and Y element, or define in the code the possible combinations.

Comment: Example for the full definition of possible combinations: `for %%I in ("Platinum A 5" "Platinum A 8" "Platinum A 9" "Platinum B 1" "Platinum B 2" "Platinum B 10" "Platinum C 4" "Platinum C 8" "Platinum C 9" "Platinum C 10") do for /F "tokens=1-3" %%x in (%%I) do` the three command lines of the most inner loop in code of question. Of course the first loop must have all 146 possible combinations. That should be no problem with maximum command line argument string(s) length limit of 8191 characters.

Comment: @Mofi - I love how you delete & keep the comments that count: the ones where you express your uncalled sarcasm and the ones where you attempt to help people out. By the way, the previous solution you've offered didn't work. I'll try the last one you're proposing and let you know. In the meantime, thank you very much and keep up the good work brother (or sister)!